# Conect mysql with mysql enterprise dll message could not load file or assembly 'mysql.data version=6.4.4.0

Tags: c#, mysql

I Created a DataAccess layer to connect any app with a mysql Database using Enterprise Library Data 5 for mysql, i used the dlls:

-EntLibContrib.Data.MySql.dll.`enter code here`
-Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.dll.
-Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.dll.

The version of each dll is 5.505.0.

i installed the full version of mysql server 5.5 with all the futures as developer machine.
In my data access layer i had a method to call a stored procedure:

```
    public DataSet ExecuteDataSet(string sp_name, object[] parameters)
    {
        try
        {
            Database BD = new MySqlDatabase(_strCon);

            DbCommand cmd = BD.GetStoredProcCommand(sp_name, parameters);

            using (DataSet ds = BD.ExecuteDataSet(cmd))
                return ds;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

I get an error in this line:

```
            Database BD = new MySqlDatabase(_strCon);
```

in my app config i have the connection string:

And the exception (FileNotFoundException) says:

Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=6.4.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assemply reference missing(MYSQL.data dll missing)

We have faced similar issues earlier..Checks to be done :

- You should check in web.config the version you have given for DLL
- MYsql.data dll version should match the version given in the DLL

You need to add reference(Dll) to the project if you havent done already.

Also you can check this [Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=6.2.2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041051/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-mysql-data-version-6-2-2-0)

Check these and rebuild again.

Thanks

Comment: correct, i just added the mysql.data.dll file and it work, thank you

Answer (score 0):

try to download the MySql.Data.dll from website 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net-ref.html

or from Nuget
open the nuget console and type Install-Package MySql.Data

Comment: thank you, i just added that dll to my project and it worked fine, regards!