# Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=6.7.4.0

Tags: c#, mysql

I have created desktop application using `C#`, having `mysql` database.
I have installed the `mysql connector` in order to connect to `mysql DB`.

when I give the absolute path till project director , I can run the application successfully.
However when i copied the `.exe` file from `bin/release` folder, application did not work.
It needs `MySql.Data.dll` in the current folder, then only it worked, how we can remove this dependency?

I checked the other properties in reference, like **Copy Local = true**.

still it is not working.

Comment: in which file did you set the CopyLocal?

Comment: probably duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13965181/conect-mysql-with-mysql-enterprise-dll-message-could-not-load-file-or-assembly/13965377#13965377

Answer (score 0):

You could *potentially* install the DLL in the GAC, but personally I wouldn't - it's simpler to deploy an application if it doesn't need any GAC entries. It's entirely normal for a .NET application to require the third-party libraries it uses to be colocated with the executable. You depend on that DLL, so it has to be available *somewhere*. Either that has to be a central place (the GAC) or alongside the exe file.

I suggest you just copy the DLL along with the executable to wherever you need them.

Another *option* would be to merge the assemblies with [ilmerge](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx), but I'd recommend against it unless you really, really have to. (I have nothing against ilmerge, but I dislike taking any steps away from the simplest deployment model unless I have to.)