# WCF and MySQL Connector

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-phone-7, mysql-connector

I created a WCF service. It uses MySQL Connector to connect to a MySQL Database. The consumer of the service is a Windows Phone app.
On my computer everything works great. But if I publish the WCF Service (on the web or on localhost), and try to use it from the phone application, it generates an error

> "The server was unable to process the request due to an internal
>   error."

By testing I found out that the error comes at the line `connection = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString);` On my laptop everything worked (when I debugged the project), I tested my WCF Service and it perfectly accessed the database and did everything well. Again, when I publish at localhost or on web, accessing the service causes an error.
[I published the log file here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5y16w41hzx4epxf/Traces7.svclog).
What is wrong? What can cause this problem?

Comment: permissions? firewall? double hops? usual suspects...

Comment: if I publish it on web or on my computer, and write "return true"  as the only line of code for the method, it will work. If I put connection = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString); it will generate an error.

Comment: Can you share details of your connection string - changing whatever in it may be sensitive?  The fact that the service works on your local machine for debugging but fails on your local machine when published makes me wonder about the security context in each case.

Comment: My connection string is: `string ConnectionString = "database=database_name;server=server_address;uid=login;pwd=password";` This declaration is exactly before the line which causes an error

Comment: Can you attach your debugger to the locally published service to see what happens when you send a request to it from the phone app?  If you know the specific line where the error occurs, maybe you have already done this; but would help to get information beyond "internal error" (e.g. an exception message and stack trace).

Comment: I added the server log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found what was the problem.
[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041051/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-mysql-data-version-6-2-2-0) helped a lot. It turned out that the problem was with MySql.Data.dll. It must be copied locally (by default that property is set to false). Without that, the program doesn't find the library and throws an exception. So I needed to change the setting to 'Copy To Local = true'