# Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=6.5.4.0

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

I know this looks like the same issue in [2041051](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041051) but I have a different question.

I have a C# app that uses MySQL 5.5.  It's built using MySQL Connector .Net 6.5.4.0 (which came with MySQL 5.5).  Everything works fine running on my computer.  When the app is run on a computer that has MySQL 5.6 installed, the app fails with the error shown in the title above.  I think MySQL 5.6 installs Connector 6.6.5.  So it seems I have a couple options:

1) Add an explicit reference to the 6.5.4.0 connector, make it Copy Local, and distribute it along with my app.

2) Make my app somehow insensitive to the specific version of the connector.  I have no idea how to do that, or if it's even possible.

3) ?

Do I understand the problem correctly?  What's the best solution?

Comment: I would just make it Copy Local, and not worry about anything else.