# BLToolkit-mysql-connector exception: Could not load file or assembly MySql.Data, Version=6.9.7.0

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, orm, bltoolkit

I am using BLToolKit (ver. 4.3.2.0) and MySql Connector (BLToolkit.Data.DataProvider.MySql.4 of version 4.3.2.0) from NuGet.
When I run my web.app in the mono-environment all work perfectly. But on the IIS I get an exception:

> FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=6.9.7.0, Culture...

What is wrong?

**UPD**: also I used the MySql.Data (from NuGet), version 6.9.8.0

Comment: I still don't know, what is the matter. I just removed all, and installed all from the scratch. Oh, and it is very important: nor MSVS, either nuget console couldn't handle its own references, saved in the project.. References and nuget packages are often contradict each other. It is [**SO SWEEET**] for developers... Oh, I like and I really love to solve such conflicts manually

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=6.2.2.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041051/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-mysql-data-version-6-2-2-0)

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess: Is the corresponding assembly in the same folder as your program (should be a library file like "MySql.dll" or "MySql.Data.dll")?

EDIT: This problem has been reported previously:
[Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=6.2.2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041051/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-mysql-data-version-6-2-2-0)

Comment: yeah, there is a file MySql.Data.dll (( Through "Properties" of the file in the explorer, I found it's version - 6.9.8

Comment: I don't know, which one of assemblies is "retrograde"... there is a new version, why that crazy assembly have taken old version of the DLL...

Comment: So it  works now? Sorry, I don't understand what you mean with your last comment.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041051/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-mysql-data-version-6-2-2-0?rq=1

Comment: thanks, @321polorex123, it is a duplicate, and the problem was solved by reinstalling and cleaning up the production PC

Answer (score 0):

I had the samen problem and resolved it with a copy of the previous version.
- Download the version you need from https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/c-net/
- install the connector on a PC (not the one you are using, it won't install
- copy the folder MySQL Connector Net 6.9.5 from C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL to the same folder on your PC.
- In Visual studio: remove the MySQL.Data-reference.
- Add the reference again using 'Addreference / Browse'
- Choose MySQL.Data.dll in the folder C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector Net version\Assemblies\v4.5